# Active Directory Kerberos issue KDC_ERR_S_PRINCIPAL_UNKNOWN

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-xp, kerberos

We are implementing a system where our clients are Windows XP and our server is Windows Server 2008 R2. Ours clients use DCOM to connect COM+ components in our Windows 2008 Server.

It works fine when the user defined in our COM+ package is a local user. However we need acces to network shares in the COM+ component, so we need to use a AD user in our COM+  package. But then we have Kerberos error : KDC_ERR_S_PRINCIPAL_UNKNOWN

So I read that it was a missing SPN. I used network monitor to trace the name of that SPN. I got a SNAME in the following format : user@domain (see screen)

If I run the following command 
setspn -s user@domain domain\user

it says the name is invalid. It expect a name in the following format :
service\host.

Anyone could point me what I am doing wrong to debug this ?

Also please note that I had a preauthentication issue in my event log before I had this issue. I desactivated the preauthentification for the user in our AD.

Thanks

http://filedb.experts-exchange.com/incoming/2013/05_w19/653312/screen-scan.JPG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using "user@domain" you should use the syntax as documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677601.aspx).

I found the following commands ("-A" parameter is changed to "-s") in this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/distributedservices/archive/2009/07/20/activation-of-a-com-component-fails-on-windows-server-2008-with-the-error-80070721.aspx).

```
setspn -s DCOMService/DCOMServer Domain\DCOMServiceAccount
setspn -s DCOMService/DCOMServerFQDN Domain\DCOMServiceAccount
```

Comment: Asked a domain admin to run the command. Will keep you informed if it works. Thanks !